# Do I need to open Salesforce Support case to be able to run Push Upgrade for the Minor or Major version of 2GMP?

Tags: second-generation-packaging, push-upgrade, 2gmp

Do I need to open Salesforce Support case to be able to run Push Upgrade for the Minor or Major version of 2GMP?

As far as I can see, to be able to perform Push Upgrade for the Major or Minor version of the classic packages (1GMP), developer needs to open Salesforce Support case to be able to run Push Upgrade. Do we need to do the same for 2GMP push upgrade requests or are they available without Salesforce Support case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2GMP SOAP API request works for minor versions as well as for patch versions.

[image]

1. Package Version should pass AppExchange Security Review. If you try to create `PackagePushRequest` with package version that hasn't passed AppExchange security, the following error occurs

   ```
   [{"message":"Specify a package that has passed the AppExchange security review.","errorCode":"INVALID_OPERATION","fields":[]}]
   ```
2. The new package version and the old package version should have the common minor version ancestor otherwise there will be error like

   ```
   The currently installed version does not share a common ancestor with this version.
   ```
3. When the source organization doesn't have old package version installed yet, the following error is displayed

   ```
   [{"message":"The specified SubscriberOrganizationKey is not eligible to receive this upgrade. It may not have the package installed, or has a beta version installed.","errorCode":"INVALID_OPERATION","fields":[]}]
   ```
4. If the organization already has installed the new package version, the following error appears

   ```
   The package version in the subscriber's organization is not eligible to receive this upgrade.
   ```